# Display names not displaying when calling DisplayFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following models. Attendance and FoodPreference are enums.

```
public class RsvpModel {

        public RsvpPerson[] People { get; set; }
    }

public class RsvpPerson {

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("Are you attending?")]
    public Attendances? IsAttending { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("Food Preference")]
    public FoodPreference? Food { get; set; }
}
```

The model is being passed in to my view

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Models.RsvpModel>" %>
```

However this displays nothing and I don't know why.

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[0].FirstName)%>
```

Comment: LabelFor is render property name, annotate DisplayNameAttribute. DisplayFor is render display template, extend UIHintAttribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must add the Labels invidually:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.People[0].FirstName) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.People[0].FirstName) %>
```